# ERROR: Failure: ModuleNotFoundError (No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy')

Tags: python, integration, travis-ci, continuous

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
import json
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
```

I have the import options in my app.py as above, the code runs well on my local machine but I get this error during travis build:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/failure.py", line 39, in runTest
    raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 235, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 684, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/travis/build/Bonifase/WeConnect-/api/test_business.py", line 2, in <module>
    import app
  File "/home/travis/build/Bonifase/WeConnect-/api/app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
```

Comment: I have a similar error when calling `reload()` to reload modules. Works on Win, GNU/Linux, OSX, Docker, yet doesn't on Travis <3 [Travis log](https://travis-ci.org/KeyWeeUsr/plyer/jobs/407804282)

Answer (score -3):

please import Flask-SQLAlchemy